# Buffer overrun issue reported by static code analysis tool

Tags: c, static-code-analysis, buffer-overrun

My piece of code:

```
void temp(char *source)
{
    char dest[41];

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        sprintf(&dest[i*2], "%02x", (unsigned int)source[i]);
    }
}
```

When I run the static code analysis tool, I get the warning below:

> On 19th iteration of the loop : This code could write past the end of the buffer pointed to by &dest[i * 2]. &dest[i * 2] evaluates to [dest + 38]. sprintf() writes up to 9 bytes starting at offset 38 from the beginning of the buffer pointed to by &dest[i * 2], whose capacity is
>   41 bytes.The number of bytes written could exceed the number of allocated bytes beyond that offset. The overrun occurs in stack memory.

My question is: since in every loop iteration, we are only copying 2 bytes (considering size of unsigned int on the machine is 2 bytes) from source to destination, where is the possibility of copying 9 bytes on the last iteration?

Comment: `considering size of unsigned int on the machine is 2 bytes` - and 2 bytes are 4 characters in hex representation, so when `i=19` you can overflow. `writes up to 9 bytes` - I think your static analysis tool doesn't know that you have `sizeof(int) = 2`. What analysis tool are you running? How did you configured the tool?

Comment: The warning is clear.  Writing `9` bytes to `dest[38]` would result in a buffer overrun.

Comment: It is possible, try it with source ending with '€' for example.  Char is a signed type for many compilers, so the cast can generate a very large unsigned int value that requires 9 characters.  The kind of gotcha that makes code analyzers useful.  Cast to (unsigned char) instead.

Answer (score 1):

`char` can be signed, and is so by default in x86 compilers. On my computer

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%02x\n", (unsigned int)(char)128);
}
```

prints `ffffff80`.

What you *want* to do is use format `"%02hhx"` and argument `(unsigned char)c`.

Comment: The same warning is reported when "source" is of type unit8_t*, considering the fact that uint8_t is typedef as unsigned char there should not any buffer overrun.

Comment: @VaibhavKulkarni i.e. the analyzer is stupid, but it did find a valid bug ;)